# IPython notebook does not have access to paths added in .bashrc, when served from AWS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am running an AWS EC2 instance with OS: Ubuntu 14.04

In my .bashrc profile I have added the following:

PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/pythonlibs

When I start a IPython notebook server instance, then access that server instance via a web-browser I do not see /home/ubuntu/pythonlibs in `sys.path` i.e.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

However, when I ssh into my AWS instance, type the `python` command and check `sys.path` it is there.

Also, when I ssh into my AWS instance, I am the user `ubuntu`.

When I start an IPython server instance, go to terminal via IPython, I am the user `root`.

So, how can I get access to all of my custom python paths defined in .bashrc, from within IPython notebooks?